# md5 password code login failed

Tags: php, authentication, md5

This is my checklogin code. I can't get log in. I think there is problem with the password. I use md5 password. Is it correct to use md5 like that as shown below ? Because the      $count keep on showing 0 not 1.

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

//function to sanitize values from the form. Preventing the SQL injection
function clean ($str){
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $str = striplashes ($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//sanitize POST values
$myusername = clean ($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = clean (md5($_POST['password']));
$role = clean ($_POST['role']);



$sql="SELECT username, password, role FROM student WHERE username='$myusername' and password='".md5($_POST['password'])."' and role = '$role'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION ['username'];
$_SESSION['password']; 
$_SESSION['role'];
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
header ("location: login_failed.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you MD5ing your password using clean, and then ignoring that and injecting md5($_POST['password']) directly in your SQL statement? That looks a bit pointless (especially as you don't need to clean password anyway as you're hashing it.

Comment: And only hashing a password with MD5 is not enough. Use a good [password encryption algorithm](http://php.net/password).

Comment: Show table values and input values?

Comment: *"md5 password code login failed"* – **Call it a "bad for a good".** You shouldn't be using `md5`, it's old tech and **insecure.** Plus you're using a deprecated `MySQL_` use `MySQLi_` with prepared statements or PDO.

Comment: @Marcel: in an attempt to learn i'd like to ask to you to kindly explain why md5 is not enough. I always thought it sufficient but i am willing to adapt.

Comment: @SquareCat - because md5 has very limited entropy, making it easy to brute force; and there's dozens of sites available that have done all that hard work already and can give you a value that will match a given hash:  hashcat can try up to [86.24M combination/s] on 8 threads on win 7 64bit.... just imaging how much raw brute force power you can put together with a cluster of cloud servers

Comment: @SquareCat There exist rainbow tables out there with *many* passwords. But the most important is: MD5 is very fast and it's easy to check thousands of passwords in a second. Good password encryption algorithms are **slow** and hash a password many times *using a salt*.

Comment: Wow, okay. I kept using md5 without giving it a further thought back since 2002. Thanks for freshening me up. Also found [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-is-cracked-since-1996) btw.

Comment: @SquareCat - current recommendation in PHP is to use the [password_*](http://www.php.net/function.password-hash)

Answer (score 1):

Your clear()-method has no rewardable benefit. stripping and escaping in general has nothing to do with sanitization. Sanitization is case-related and could not be generialized.

For sanitization / validation have a look at: http://php.net/filter

Sanitization or Validation would not prevent SQL-Injection. You have to...

- Escape the value with the escape function of the database interface ( pdo::quote(), mysqli_real_escape_string() - but not mysql_real_escape_string() because it's deprecated )
- directly bind the values into prepared statements ( value binding in prepared statements is the most secure way, because the value would be piped into the database-field and not concatinated into the query-string )

If you are using PHP 5.5.0 or higher, you may prefer: http://php.net/password_hash
In lower PHP Versions, you've to salt manually: http://php.net/passwords

At least, location-headers are invalid if they are not defined as full qualified urls.

Comment: From PHP 5.3.7 onwards, you can use a compatibility library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: Yes, but i personally avoid pointing to libraries which are extending the global namespace in any way. ( I do not recommend my behaviour, it's just what i decided while handle libraries and spread their availability to the community )

Answer (score 0):

I'll be direct - using MD5 is the worst option possible. Stop, just stop.
Also:

```
password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'
```

Change that to

```
password='".$mypassword."'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use plain hashing, use salting
2. Do not use md5, it's known to be broken.
3. Use prepared statements in your queries
4. Consider Indenting your code properly
5. Avoid Session Hijacking.. Furthermore, i can see no session_start(),
6. By the HTTP Standard, the Location Header expects non-relative URL
7. ...

Comment: About 6: all browsers work with relative URLs, the standard is to be modified accordingly.

Comment: most browsers have some kind of quirks mode in html, that does not make invalid html valid.. i can see your point but i am just citing the standard here